# How to delete populated id from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I make a post and I populate the comment into the post by using the populate method I want to delete the comment and the ref of the comment on the post, I can delete the comment but the ref it doesn't want to delete

```
const { ObjectID } = require("mongodb");
    const { Comment, Post } = require("../models/User-Post");
    module.exports = commentControlleur = {
      addComment: async (req, res) => {
        const userId = ObjectID(req.params.userId);
        const postId = ObjectID(req.params.postId);
        const { body, date } = req.body;
        try {
          const newComment = new Comment({
            body,
            date,
            postId,
            userId,
          });
          try {
            Comment.create(newComment, (err, doc) => {
              if (err) res.status(503).json({ errors: err });
              else {
                Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
                  postId,
                  { $push: { comments: doc } },
                  { new: true },
                  (err, data) => {
                    if (err) res.status(504).json({ errors: err });
                    else {
                      res.status(200).json(newComment);
                    }
                  }
                );
              }
            });
          } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ errors: error });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          res.status(501).json({ errors: error });
        }
      },
```

This is how I add comment in the post schema

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
  title: String,
  date: String,
  body: String,
  postType: String,
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "comment",
      autopopulate: true,
    },
  ],
});

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "post",
  },
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
  body: String,
  date: String,
});
```

But when I delete the comment the ref in the comments in the post doesn't delete this is how I write the code of the delete

```
deleteComment: async (req, res) => {
    const postId = ObjectID(req.params.postId);
    const { id } = req.body;
    try {
      const searchDeleteCommment = await Comment.findOneAndDelete({ _id: id });
      if (searchDeleteCommment)
        Post.update(
          {_id: postId }, 
          { $pull: {comments: id} }
          );
      res.status(200).json({ msg: "comment deleted" });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(501).json({ errors: error });
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

While using pull comment id should be in ObjectID format

```
deleteComment: async (req, res) => {
    const postId = ObjectID(req.params.postId);
    const { id } = req.body;
    try {
      const searchDeleteCommment = await Comment.findOneAndDelete({ _id: id });
      if (searchDeleteCommment)
        await Post.update(
          {_id: postId }, 
          { $pull: {comments: ObjectID(id)} }
          );
      res.status(200).json({ msg: "comment deleted" });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(501).json({ errors: error });
    }
  },
```

Comment: The comment is deleted from comment collection?

Comment: yes it's deleted but the ref id in the post dosen't wan't to delete

Comment: Your code looks fine, just await was missing from update query, can you please add sample post data from database, how the comment data is saved in post collection

Comment: _id : ObjectID("5eb44416f6f9521f84031cb5")

title :"title1"
body:"body of title1"
date:"07/05/2020"
postType:"idea"
userId:Object("5ea82e7a64fbcd04bcd6e429")
__v:0
comments:Array
0:ObjectID("5ec5bc679a9f1326f873df2a")
1:ObjectID("5ec5bc689a9f1326f873df2b")
2:ObjectID("5ec5bc6a9a9f1326f873df2c")
3:ObjectID("5ec5bc6a9a9f1326f873df2d")

Comment: Sorry mate, can't deduce what's the issue :(